# How to write the value of an environment variable into a text file?

Tags: batch-file, variables

I need to write a decimal value assigned to environment variable `finalval` into a text file as such:

```
echo.%%finalval>>^C:\TempSetup\id.txt
```

The problem is that after execution when I go to check the file content the actual value of `finalval` isn't written into the file, instead it's just written `%finalval%`.
In previous usages in the same batch file of the same style of `echo` command, I've had no problems.

I have `enabled delayedexpansion` both in the first line as well as the loop I am using to write into the file.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Batch File: Output variable to text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25472541/batch-file-output-variable-to-text-file)

Comment: The correct line for this task is: `>>"C:\TempSetup\id.txt" echo(%finalval%` The redirection is put first on the command line to be able to output also values like `1`, `2`, etc. For a detailed explanation see my answer on [Why does ECHO command print some extra trailing space into the file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46972524/3074564) The round bracket between command `echo` and the output value makes it possible to get an empty line written into the file if the variable `finalval` is not defined at all instead of writing the echo state into the file.

Comment: Delayed environment variable expansion is only needed if the environment variable `finalval` holds a string which could contain characters having a special meaning for the Windows command processor `cmd.exe` processing the batch file as described by [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/) In this case it would be really necessary to enable [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) and use it with `echo(!finalval!>>"C:\TempSetup\id.txt"`. It is safe with delayed expansion to append the redirection.

Comment: @Mofi thank you very much for your help, it's appreciated

Answer (score 0):

There is a method which appears to be little used, but works well when you're certain that your `echo` string does not begin with a character which is escapable. The method is to escape using the standard escape character, *(the caret, `^`)*:

```bat
@For %%A In (0 1 2 3.0 4.1 5.2 10 21 32 String0 "String 1" "0 1 2")Do @Echo(^%%~A>>CON
```

I have used `CON` in the above code to redirect to the console device, you can obviously change that to a file for your specific task after testing.

The output should look something like this:

> ```bat
> 0
> 1
> 2
> 3.0
> 4.1
> 5.2
> 10
> 21
> 32
> String0
> String 1
> 0 1 2
> ```

As a result of jeb's comment, just to clarify, the idea can be more simply shown using:

```bat
@Echo(^%%finalval>>"C:\TempSetup\id.txt"
```

Where `%%finalval` is used to represent, *(should be replaced by)*, the reported variable containing the 'decimal' value.

Comment: It works, .. but it also works without the caret, because the `%%~A` is expanded when the redirection is already parsed. I suppose you wanted to show that something like `echo Helllo ^2>con` works (showing `Hello 2`)

Comment: Yes @jeb, but I wanted to keep the answer as generic as possible, _as the OP didn't provide any detail only a single snippet which only looked like it 'may' have been `do` output_. I just figured that the OP would understand that `%%~A` is merely a representation of their `%%finalval`, _and the rest is technically irrelevant to their specific issue_.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to enableDelayedExpansion, if you're not expanding the variable later in your script. If you've already set "finalval" earlier:

```
set finalval=someNumber
```

This is how you call it later:

```
echo.%finalval% >>C:\TempSetup\id.txt
```

Note: When you're redirecting the output to "id.txt", a single carat > will create the file. Double carats >> will append the file. Meaning, if you continue to run the script, and you're expecting a single value of "X" to be in "id.txt", since you're using double carats, your output will reflect "X" as many times as you've ran the script.

Comment: It would probably be wise to explain that this solution `echo`es `<Decimal><Space>`, not `<Decimal>`.